# log4js not recognized by intelliSense of VisualStudio 2017

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2017, log4js-node

My NodeJS project is written in Typescript 2.5

The following import line for the module:

```
import log4js= require('log4js);
```

compiles and i use the logger successfully. Even IntelliSense prompts the object method and properties well. Yet, i got following the annoying error from IntelliSense:

> TS2307    (TS) Cannot find module 'log4js'.

If i try to add the respective types to my project but i got the message:

```
npm install @types/log4js --only=dev
npm WARN deprecated @types/log4js@2.3.5: This is a stub types definition    for log4js (https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node). log4js provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/log4js installed!
```

Comment: You need to install `log4js` in addition to `@types/log4js`

Comment: but i add. If not, it wouldn't run.

Comment: If you're using TypeScript you should use `import { getLogger } from 'log4js';`

Comment: Following your tip i put to work, but passing the full path instead just the module name: ´../../node_modules/log4js/types/log4js´. Should be a way to reference the module without the path.

Comment: Yes, it should just be `'log4js/types/log4js'`

Comment: import { getLogger } from 'log4js'
also works. I just need to compile. Still use to get all errors before compiling.